# RPM of a motor from frequency

Tags: motor, frequency, sound, rpm

I have a very old motor which I can't find any information about. I need to calculate its RPM for some work. I've attached a cog to it, held a piece of paper up to it and recorded the pitch. It was around **300Hz**.

Can I use this in any way to calculate its RPM and if not, are there any other tests I could possible carry out?

I'm using it with a gearbox including 5 30:8 gear ratios. The final RPM of the last gear is about 1.5RPM. By this, it should be about 750RPM but this doesn't seem right. The starting cog has 8 teeth.

Comment: Doubtful. Is it an induction motor? Maybe a picture could help.

Comment: I forgot to mention. It is a motor that was used in a vacuum. Does this help? I have also added more information about the project which may be useful.

Comment: (30/8)^5 ~= 741.6 so if your output shaft is 1.5 rpm, your input must be 1112 rpm. -- why not state the number of teeth on your gear?

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Thanks - I'll add it now, but it's 8.

Comment: well 300 hz / 8 teeth * 60 s/min is 2250 rpm. after those five reductions, that would have to be 3 rpm. to check: 1.5 rpm means one revolution in 40 seconds. how did you measure those 300 hz?

Comment: Yes, it's definitely 1.5RPM (10 seconds to go 45 degrees) - unless there's just a lot of friction...

Comment: 45 degrees are _half_ a right angle. a full revolution has eight 45-degree pieces, so your revolution would have to be 80 seconds, which makes this 0.75 rpm.

Comment: Sorry, I was working in radians so coverted incorrectly by mistake - 90 degrees**.

Comment: install a stroboscope app on your phone

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can!  300Hz is also 18000 cycles/minute.  Now all you need to to is to divide by the number of teeth on your cog and you have the RPM.

Let's say there are 100 teeth on the cog.  So that gives us:

300 Hz * 60 sec/minute = 18000 cycles/min
18000/100 teeth = 180 RPM

Now all you need to do is count the number of teeth on your cog!

Comment: So there are 8 teeth on the cog (it's very small) meaning this would be 2250 RPM. However in my gearbox there are 5 30:8 gear ratios ending at 1.5RPM (10 seconds to go 45 degrees). This suggests the starting RPM is 750. I'm not sure which is correct.

Comment: @ChrisMartin Well, 2250 is exactly three times 750. Is it possible that the fundamental frequency is actually 100 Hz and you're measuring the third harmonic? Is there a significant amount of sound at 500 Hz or 700 Hz?

Comment: "18000/100 teeth = 1800 RPM" may contain an arithmetic error

Comment: Yes, you're right.  I corrected it.